# How do I make wordpress comment fields required?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Here is my form:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="validate">  
   <?php if($user_ID) : ?>  
   <?php else : ?>
   <div class="label_container">
      <div class="left">
         <label for="author" class="label label_name">Name*</label>                 
      </div>
      <div class="right">
         <label for="email" class="label label_email">Email*</label>              
      </div>
      </div>
   <div class="input_container">
      <input id="name" name="author" class="required input_text input_name" type="text" value="" /> 
      <input id="email" name="email" class="required input_text email input_email" type="text" value="" />
   </div>         
   <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="label_container"> 
         <label for="comment" class="label label_comment">Comment</label>                 
      </div>
   <textarea id="comment_box" class="required input_comment" name="comment" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>   
   <p><input name="submit" class="input_submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit Comment" />  
   <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /></p>  
   <input type="hidden" id="redirect_to" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl');?>/comment">
   <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>  
</form>
```

I have required fields on all inputs, but it is only working on the comment text field.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be better off asking this at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There is a WordPress SE site now? Wow ok, it is getting pretty specialised around here, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: It is totally dead in there...

Comment: Dude, you asked the question six minutes ago. People have lives. Give it time.

Comment: @eykanal I don't mean no one has replied already, I am looking at older questions and the views they have had already... I guess this is a discussion for the meta rather than here, but creating such niche sites is going to cause a problem.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Well, hopefully enough people from the wordpress community read this site also.

Comment: Most of the action is in the wordpress.org/support forums. Although I much prefer the SO/SE interface (for scoring, searching, etc.), there are years and years of support history in those forums.

Comment: WPSE is still young, give it a chance.. it has a good user base at the moment, and will continue to grow.. :) I've just arrived here after using WPSE(which was my first SO/SE experience).. for ref: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5297/how-do-i-make-wordpress-comment-fields-required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can actually control that from the `settings` `discussion tab` in the `wp-admin` panel.

make sure to check `Comment author must fill out name and e-mail`. that should do it.

is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

if you want client side validation then use

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

and if you want server side validation then use php

like

```
if(empty($_POST['email']))
{ 
  //show error msg
}else{
 //add comment
}
```